# Update table using 2 columns in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-update

Hi there i have this code which is having an error when i try to run it.

```
s.executeUpdate("UPDATE [salesRecord] SET [backOrder] = 'backOrder'," +
" [quantity] ='"+ conDiff +"'" +
"WHERE [productID] = '" + s1 +"' AND [orderNumber] = '"+valueOrder+"' " );
```

the purpose of this code is to set orders as back orders when all items are not delivered. i want to specify which product i will update by setting my where to look for that item using productID and orderNumber.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] 
Too few parameters. Expected 1.
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
```

Above is the error that shows when i try to run the program.

Comment: does s1 or valueOrder have ? in them? Anyway, in general use bind parameters, not concatenated queries

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the following
```

Let backOrder , conDiff , s1, valueOrder be the variables.

```
   s.executeUpdate("UPDATE [salesRecord] SET [backOrder] = '"+backOrder+"',[quantity] ='"+ conDiff +"' WHERE [productID] = '" + s1 +"' AND [orderNumber] = '"+valueOrder+"' " );
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have written is not using any parameters, but the error message says it is expecting one.  This means that your "**s**" is probably being reused from somewhere else before and, that is using a parameter.

Seeing as you are using Java, I assume **s** is a java.sql.PreparedStatement or similar and that a parameter has been set using any one of the **s.setXXX(parameterIndex, value)** methods.

more details see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html

The *simple* solution is to use *new statement*.